# The Name 'X' does not exist in the current contexxt

Tags: asp.net, object, linq-to-sql

I've looked on the web for around a week for this issue and (not being overly technical and trying to learn) I'm really struggling.

I am following an online guide to create a cascading dropdown using Web Form objects (as I gather this is the simplest way to do it)

Extract from my ASPX pageb elow

Under Body I have:

```
    <section id="banner">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Cabin Reviews</h2>
        <p>Straight From The Cruise</p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="dropotron">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlClines"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div class="dropotrontwo">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShips" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Under my "Code Behind" I have:

```
 public partial class MainMenuDropdown : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlClines.DataSource = GetData("spGetCruiseLines", null);
            ddlClines.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

the object "ddlClines though is not being recognised by the page behind.  I've seen other threads where people have suggested re-creating the designer file.  I've tried this with no success.  I've taken my code to work and asked experienced web developers to see what I'm obviously doing wrong and even they were at a loss.  I really want to get this off the ground but its a struggle with little knowledge.

Thanks folks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

In your markup you have "ddlCLines", whereas in your code-behind you have "ddlClines".

Comment: My bad, I have corrected this several times, but I can confirm it doesn't make a difference :-(

Comment: This does happen and tweaking the designer file is not a good move. I would re-create the page from scratch.

Comment: This is my 4th attempt #Sadness

Comment: Try and create another page and rename it to something else. Then copy/paste your code/markup>